# How to get the compass mixin transform-origin to take effect

Tags: css, sass, transform

I've a strange problem with `transform`s in compass.

I want to move the axis with `transform-origin(50% 100%)` to the bottom, which is working if i type it into firebug.

But if I use the mixin `@include transform-origin(50% 100%)` it's not visible in firebug.
Only the rotation part is applied `@include transform(perspective(600px) rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg));`.

In compiled CSS I can find this line but it's not applied somehow and written with three values.
`-moz-transform-origin:50% 100% 50%;`

My SASS looks like this:

```
div#loader {
  @include transition-property(transform);
  @include transition-duration(3s);
  @include transform(perspective(600px) rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg));
  @include transform-origin(50% 100%); // This is not taking affect in final css
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

What could be the reason for that?

If I write the line `-moz-transform-origin:50% 100%;`directly in my SASS it's working too.

Comment: Update. I'm using autoprefixer now which automatically updates the generated css code and add vendor prefixes into it. https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Compass think, that you pass only one parametr(without comma) and try to add another. In the documentation of the compass you can find this comment:

```
// Transform-origin sent as individual arguments:
//
//     @include transform-origin( [ origin-x, origin-y, origin-z, 3D-only ] )
```

so you should use the following code:

```
@include transform-origin(50%, 100%);
```

Comment: I used include transform-origin(50% 100%) as written in question... "But if I use the mixin include transform-origin(50% 100%) it's not visible in firebug"

Comment: @Bernhard  sorry:) I forgot to put the comma